# Vim is showing a different color when setting it up in .vimrc file than when selected it manually when Vim is running

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

I am experimenting color schemes for vim, and it isn't the first time the same scheme of colors shows differently when I set it manually by typing `color [file name].vim` and setting it up in my `.vimrc`.

For example, the colors I'm trying to set up is [`burnttoast256`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/burnttoast256/blob/master/colors/burnttoast256.vim). When I select it manually inside running Vim, it shows like this:

[image]

But then, when exiting and entering Vim, the following:

[image]

If I select the colors via `color` or `colorscheme` command, it will correctly show the colors.

I already experienced some other color schemes that I needed to remove `set background=256` for an accurate display, but in the case of this one, removing it doesn't solve.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure that your `.vimrc` isn't doing something else to adjust the colors and/or color scheme?

Comment: Apparently the first 3 lines after `colorscheme` were the cause, but I do not understand very well the reason since when I select a color manually it should be affected by the same configuration.

Comment: Configuration is applied in order.  When you select it manually, you're doing so after whatever in your vimrc that made the undesired change was applied, so the new change overrode the old.